Flow formula resulting in null value
I have a flow formula that seems to be resulting in "null" when I check the debug log and it is not returning a negative value so I suspect there may be something erroring out or simply not calculating:
{!$Record.Total_Currency__c} - ( {!$Record.Fee_Calc_1__c}+ {!$Record.Fee_1__c}+{!$Record.Fee_2__c}+ {!$Record.Fee_3__c}+{!$Record.Fee_4__c} + {!$Record.Fee_5__c}+{!$Record.Fee_6__c}+{!$Record.Fee_7__c}+{!$Record.Fee_8__c}+ {!$Record.Fee__9} ) - {!$Record.Credit__c}
For example:
Total currency = $929,995.00
Fee Calc 1 = $29,701.85
Fee 1 = $1,100.00
Fee 2 = $299.00
Fee 3 = $35.00
Fee 4 = $0.00
Fee 5 = $499.00
Fee 6 = $0.00
Fee 7  = $22,165.68
Fee 8 = $3,612.46
Fee 9  = $1,500.00
Credit = $0.00
Expected amount: 874,082.01
Current result from salesforce flow formula: null

In a normal formula field, there's an option (under the area that you enter the formula in) with two options: 1) Treat blanks as blanks. 2) Treat blanks as zeroes. Is there a similar option when you create a flow formula? If so, which option have you selected? Do the fields you indicate have $0.00 as the value actually have that value, or are they null/blank?

Also, is $Record.Fee_9 a typo, or is that actually how it appears in your formula?


I believe I have treat blanks as zeroes. I double checked the field values and they are all  populated/ not $0.00
It is a typo sorry, scrubbed this post for confidentiality


Update: I tested the formula just adding up the fee values and it is still returning null. All these fields are positive values and are populated - ever run into this?

The formula seems fine, I'd suggest removing most fields and adding them back one by one. That might give you an indication of where your problem starts.

Thank you. That was it.  One of the fields was blank and I needed to add BLANKVALUE() to count it as a zero.

That shouldn't have been a problem if you had "treat blanks as zeroes" selected as you indicated. Double checking things, it appears that the blank treatment options are not available on flow formulas. That would definitely explain why you needed to use BLANKVALUE().
